# Difference between balanced_accuracy_score and accuracy_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am using balanced_accuracy_score and accuracy_score both in sklearn.metrics.

According to documentation, those two metrics are the same but in my code, the first is giving me 96% and the second one is 97% while accuracy from training is 98%

Can you explain to me what is the difference between the three accuracies and how each is computed?

Note: the problem is a multi-classification problem with three classes.

I have attached code samples.

**accuracy is 98%**

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**accuracy is 96%**

```
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score
balanced_accuracy_score(all_labels, all_predications)
```

**accuracy is 97%**

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(all_labels, all_predications)
```

Comment: You forgot to share your code, which would make it way more easy to reproduce your problem

Comment: I have added code samples

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem (without knowing what all_labels, all_predictions) is run on, the difference in your out of sample predictions between `balanced_accuracy_score` and `accuracy_score` is caused by the balancing of the former function.

[`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) simply returns the percentage of labels you predicted correctly (i.e. there are 1000 labels, you predicted 980 accurately, i.e. you get a score of 98%.

[`balanced_accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html) however works differently in that it returns the average accuracy per class, which is a different metric. Say your 1000 labels are from 2 classes with 750 observations in class 1 and 250 in class 2. If you miss-predict 10 in each class, you have an accuracy of 740/750= 98.7% in class 1 and 240/250=96% in class 2. `balanced_accuracy_score` would then return (98.7%+96%)/2 = 97.35%. So I believe the program to work as expected, based on the documentation.

Comment: Strangely the documentation of `balanced_accuracy_score` says it is the average of *recall* which I think should be a mistake.

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of recall. In Sklearn's online guide they cite Mosley (2013) (https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/etd/13537) and given that author's definition of recall the `balanced_accuracy_score` calculation seems accurate. Then again, you can use other weighting rules than just divide sum of recall per class by the number of all classes.

Answer (score 7):

Accuracy = tp+tn/(tp+tn+fp+fn)  doesn't work well for unbalanced classes.

Therefore we can use Balanced Accuracy = TPR+TNR/2

TPR= true positive rate = tp/(tp+fn) : also called 'sensitivity'

TNR = true negative rate= tn/(tn+fp) : also caled 'specificity'

Balanced Accuracy gives almost the same results as ROC AUC Score.

Links:

1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

2 https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score

3 https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html

Comment: I don't believe balanced accuracy is "almost the same" as AUC. With my data, AUC is 0.75 but balanced accuracy is only 0.54